# Dojo dnd target and page loading

Tags: dojo, shopping-cart, target, drag-and-drop

My question is related to the dnd example (Step 4: listening to events) posted at http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2011/12/05/dojo-drag-n-drop-redux/.

In my case I have multiple dnd sources that span several pages. How do I record the data in the shopping cart (target) so that the items in it do not disappear after loading different pages and that users can continue to drop more items?

Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

see [dojotoolkit.org](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:dojotoolkit.org%20dojo%20dnd%20source)

Seems docs are not upstream for the 1.7 listings however;

subscribe to a set of topics and you will know when/what is drapped

[dojo.topic.subsribe](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/dnd#summary-of-topics)

- /dnd/**start**: when DnD starts. Current source, nodes, and copy flag
  (see Manager's startDrag() for more info) are passed as parameters of
  this event.
- ./dnd/**source/over** : when the mouse moves over a source. The source in
  question is passed as a parameter. The same event is raised when the
  mouse goes out of a source. In this case null is passed as a
  parameter.
- /dnd/**drop/before**: raised just before the drop. It can be used to
  capture the drop parameters. Parameters are the same as for
  /dnd/drop.
- /dnd/**drop**: raised to perform a drop. The first three parameters are
  the same as for /dnd/start. The fourth parameter is the target
  object. Note that during the processing of this event nodes can be
  already moved, or reused. If you need the original nodes, use
  /dnd/drop/before to capture them, or use events local to
  source/target objects.
- /dnd/**cancel** :when DnD was cancelled either by user (by hitting Esc),
  or by dropping items in illegal location. This topic has no
  parameters.

Example of topic subscription:

```
dojo.subscribe("dnd/start", function(source, nodes, copy) {
  // see dojo.dnd.startDrag documentation for details
  // this event will process when user picks up a dnditem
  console.log("Arguments:", arguments);

};
dojo.subscribe("dnd/drop", function(source, nodes, copy, target) {
  // see dojo.dnd.startDrag documentation for details
  // this event will process when user releases dnditem on a valid target
  // note the extra parameter, target - in 99% cases a DOM node
  console.log("Arguments:", arguments);
});
```

What happens is, user picks up item - and dndmanager calls dojo.publish("dnd/start", this.source, this.selection, this.bCopy). While subscribing to the topic you will get the notification.

dojo.topic works as if you had subscribed to a mailing-list, you would receive mail once news are available

Comment: Thanks mschr. Unfortunately, I am new to dojo, so I can't seem to see the connection between the event handlers you pointed out above and the solution to my problem. I guess I can ask my question this way. The first page (page1.html) has source1 and target containers. However, source 2 must be on the second page (page2.html). How do I handle the target so that it shows up on page2, accept more items, and displays those from page1?

Comment: try add the above example to your codebase and inspect the arguments through a console

Comment: mschr, now I can get the data in the shopping cart on page1.html. However, how do I bring the SAME shopping cart (target) to page2.html with the items dropped from source1 on page1.html in it? Or should I create another target? I would greatly appreciate it if you could give me some tips.

Comment: then you have two options, one; send an ajax request to server on each addition to cart and two; most commonly used is persistent cookies, say if you have an id on each draggable - store it in cookie `dojo.cookie("mycart", idlist)`, then on serverside you will receive the cookie when page2.html (need to use other then .html..) and you may arrange a copy of your draggable into the cart - so its there when constructing it

Answer (score 0):

You wish to initialize your cart with the items that user has selected for purchase, every drop should

```
<script>
    function dropped(source, nodes, copy, target) {
      if(target.id == "myCardId") {
        var list = dojo.cookie("mycart");
        // split or initialize list (delimiter : comma)
        list = list = "" ? [] : list.split(",");
        if(dojo.indexOf(nodes[0].id), list) != -1)
           // allready there, return
           return;
        else {
           // combine list with every dropped node
           dojo.forEach(nodes, function(dropItem) { list.push(dropItem.id); });
           // set cookie with new variable
           dojo.cookie("mycart", list.join(",");
        }
      }
    }

    ....
   dojo.subscribe("dnd/drop", dropped);
</script>
```

Could be implemented in PHP like so, while i wont go in details with how you get the items view, for sake of the example - you have them in db_data;

```
<?php

if(isset($_COOKIE) && !empty($_COOKIE['mycart'])) {
   $cartContents = "<ul class=\"dndContainer\">";
   foreach(explode(",", $_COOKIE['mycart']) as $id)
      $cartContents .= "<li class=\"dndItem\">".$db_data[$id]->title."</li>";
   $cartContent .= "</ul>";
}
?>
<div id="dragSource"><? print generateView(); ?></div>
<div id="myCartId"><? print $cartContents; ?></div>
```

alternatively for large carts, a cookie is overkill and will clutter headers
    the above script could then send XHR with an id and server then append it to
    session, using same logic as the javascript does - in that case, just replace
    $_COOKIE with $_SESSION